# Definition of a sheaf: What is $s\rvert_{V_i}$ if $V_i\not\subseteq U$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, sheaf-theory

I am reading Hartshorne's book on algebraic geometry, which defines a sheaf to be a presheaf $\mathscr F$ on a topological space $X$ such that:

- For all open sets $U$ and open coverings $\{V_i\}$ of $U$ in $X$, if $s\in\mathscr F(U)$ with $\forall i.\;s\rvert_{V_i}=0$, then $s=0$;
- (more requirements)

However, the restriction maps $\cdot\,\rvert_V\colon\;\mathscr F(U)\to \mathscr F(V)$ were previously only defined if $V\subseteq U$. How does this definition handle the case that $V_i\not\subseteq U$? Does one only consider those sets $V_i$ of the covering that *are* fully contained in $U$?

Comment: By an open covering of $U$ he means a collection $\{V_i\}$ of open subsets of $U$ such that $\bigcup_i V_i=U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember being confused about this when I first started learning sheaves. In sheaf theory, one always takes open covers *by subsets* for just this reason.

If it gives you some peace of mind, note that if you have an open cover $\{V_i\}$ of an *open* set $U$, you can always replace it by the open cover *by subsets* $\{U\cap V_i\}$.

Also, only considering the open sets of a cover which happen to be contained in $U$ wont work because there are many open covers which have no such sets (the whole space $X$ covers $U$ for example), yet the first bullet then would say sections on $U$ are zero.